# Find the norm of matrix using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Tags: matrices, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, random-matrices, matrix-norms

> Let $A$ be $n \times n$ matrix and such that all of its entries are uniformly $O(1)$. Using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, show that the operator norm of matrix $A$, which is
>
> $$\|A\|_{op} := \sup_{x\in R^n: |x|=1}|Ax|$$ is  of $O(n)$.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using [this definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm) of the operator norm? I'm asking because in a class I took we used a different (not quite equivalent) definition ...

Comment: I've added the definition. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: show $|(Ax)_i| \le K \sqrt{n}$ for each $i$, then
$\|Ax\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n |(A x)_i|^2 \le K^2 n^2$.

Comment: I am little bit confused with $\|Ax\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^n|(Ax)_i|^2$. What is $\|Ax\|$ and $|(Ax)_i|$?

Comment: $\|Ax\|$ is the Euclidean norm of $Ax$ (in your notation it is $|Ax|$).  $|(Ax)_i|$ is the absolute value of the $i$'th entry of $Ax$.

Comment: Thank you, but now I am confused with the first step. Each entry of $A$ is of $O(1)$, and you saying it is $\leq K \sqrt{n}$...

Comment: Each entry $a_{ij}$ is $O(1)$.  $\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}^2}$ is $O(\sqrt{n})$

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the application of the Cauchy Schwarz (notice no t) comes in, so what I am about to write may have limited applicability, but it may be of some use:

$||Ax||=||x_{1}Ae_{1}+...+x_{n}Ae_{n}||<|x_{1}| ||Ae_{1}||+...+|x_{n}|||Ae_{n}||$ by the triangle inequality. Let $M=max(Ae_{1},Ae_{2}...,Ae_{n})$. Also $||x||=1$, so $|x_{i}|\leq 1$, so

$||Ax||<nM$

Comment: Not good enough: $\|A e_i\|$ could be of order $\sqrt{n}$.